# FacesMessage a4j:commandButton prevents from displaying a:errors

Tags: jsf, richfaces, alfresco

I have the following jsp page that has the following lib imports:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/alfresco.tld" prefix="a"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
<%@ page buffer="32kb" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ page import="org.alfresco.web.app.Application"%>
<%@ page import="org.alfresco.web.ui.common.PanelGenerator"%>
```

when i click on Finish button i should have it disabled and the action function should be automatically fired like the following :

```
<td align="center">

<a4j:commandButton
id="finish-button" styleClass="wizardButton"
value="#{msg.finish_button}"
action="#{creationReclamationBean.terminerReclamation}"
onclick="this.disabled=true;"/>

</td>
```

The content of the function is the following :

```
public String terminerReclamation() throws SQLException {
        if (!journeeServiceMetier.estJourOuvre(reclamationVO
                .getReclamationEtape3VO().getDateReclamation())) {
            Utils.addErrorMessage("La date de la demande "
                    + reclamationVO.getReclamationEtape3VO()
                            .getDateReclamation()
                    + " ne correspond pas à un jour ouvré ");
            return null;
        } else if (ireclamationServiceV4.ReclamationExiste(reclamationVO
                .getOrdinal(), reclamationVO.getReclamationEtape3VO()
                .getDateReclamation(), reclamationVO.getReclamationEtape3VO()
                .getActivite().toString(), reclamationVO
                .getReclamationEtape3VO().getProduitSelection().toString(),
                reclamationVO.getReclamationEtape3VO()
                        .getOperationselectionne().toString(), reclamationVO
                        .getEtape1vo().getSiegeSelection(), reclamationVO
                        .getEtape1vo().getRacine())
                && !reclamationVO.isModeModif()) {
            Utils.addErrorMessage("Cette réclamation existe déjà");

            return null;
}
```

when i am debugging the code, the debugging process enters in the "else" conditional statement and the line below is executed but the message doesn't appear in my page.

previously when i used the following component :

```
   <h:commandButton
    id="finish-button" styleClass="wizardButton"
    value="#{msg.finish_button}"
    action="#{creationReclamationBean.terminerReclamation}"
    onclick="this.disabled=true;"
     />
```

instead of a4j:commandButton the error message is displayed normally but the button is not disabled at all.

Can anyone of you give me a help

Thanks

Comment: PLEASE Don't **abuse** the PrimeFaces tag. There is **nothing** PrimeFaces related in this question. a4j does not work right with PrimeFaces, You have richfaces namespace declarations. I'll remove the PrimeFaces tag once more...

Comment: Do you use any message component? What does the `Utils.addErrorMessage` do? (Your if-else code is irrelevant, you only need to create the message to show the problem)

Comment: @Makhiel the Utils.addErrorMessage does the following : 


 public static void addErrorMessage(String msg, Throwable err)  
 {    
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
    msg, msg);
  
  facesMsg.getDetail();
  
  context.addMessage(null, facesMsg);
 }

Comment: Please edit your question, nobody wants to go through unformatted code.